# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pagespeed

While working on the performance of my WP website, I stumbled upon an error stating: "Use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance".

I found [this solution to it](https://howtofix.tips/en/lighthouse-fix-uses-passive-listeners-to-improve-scrolling-performance.html) and that error disappeared, although **it was substituted by a new error (Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation)**. The current error **appears repeatedly** and Google's Pagespeed Insights **links it to `jquery.min.js`**, although I'm not sure about the correct way to fix it.

Should I make any changes in the jQuery file? Should I modify the code that fixed the "Use passive listeners..." error (you can see it below)?

**EDIT:** I located the exact, problematic `preventDefault()` and following [the advice from Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19347206/patrick-hume), I simply deleted it and the issue has been solved, my website is now running smoothly.

```
(function() {
  var supportsPassive = eventListenerOptionsSupported();  

  if (supportsPassive) {
    var addEvent = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
    overwriteAddEvent(addEvent);
  }

  function overwriteAddEvent(superMethod) {
    var defaultOptions = {
      passive: true,
      capture: false
    };

    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, options) {
      var usesListenerOptions = typeof options === 'object';
      var useCapture = usesListenerOptions ? options.capture : options;

      options = usesListenerOptions ? options : {};
      options.passive = options.passive !== undefined ? options.passive : defaultOptions.passive;
      options.capture = useCapture !== undefined ? useCapture : defaultOptions.capture;

      superMethod.call(this, type, listener, options);
    };
  }

  function eventListenerOptionsSupported() {
    var supported = false;
    try {
      var opts = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
        get: function() {
          supported = true;
        }
      });
      window.addEventListener("test", null, opts);
    } catch (e) {}

    return supported;
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a passive event listener you're making a promise not to use a preventDefault() in that listener to disable scrolling. This frees the browser up to respond to scrolling immediately without waiting for JavaScript. A passive event listener is mainly used in touch start or touch move or wheel listeners.  This ensures a reliable smooth scrolling experience, in theory.

So you can either remove the preventDefault() in the event listener or
mark the event listener not being passive but I wouldn't recommend that. Try testing what happens when you remove the preventDefault() and in theory, it should work the same

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I have finally isolated the problematic preventDefault, it's this one: `this.originalEvent;this.isDefaultPrevented=we,e&&!this.isSimulated&&e.preventDefault()},`. I understand I should delete the `e.preventDefault()`, is that correct? Should I delete a larger chunk of it?

Comment: I just deleted it as you recommended and the problem is now solved, thank you so much Patrick!

Comment: no problem glad i was able to help